# IE10 CSS animation issue

Tags: html, css, animation, fade, internet-explorer-11

The problem I'm having is that a small section of a website I have built works perfectly on all browsers and on old versions of IE but not on the newest versions. As you may know, IE no longer supports [IF] statements in HTML and doesn't seem to support the  command. My problem is with a small animation of a few images using the following CSS:

```
.fadein img {
    position:absolute;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    -webkit-animation-name: fade;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 32s;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 32s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    20% {opacity: 1;}
    33% {opacity: 0;}
    53% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}
@keyframes fade {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    20% {opacity: 1;}
    33% {opacity: 0;}
    53% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}
#f1 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -4s;
}
#f2 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -8s;
}
#f3 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -16s;
}
#f4 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -24s;
}
#f5 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -32s;
}
```

this is currently in use on the web page http://www.portsmouthtap.co.uk to few quotes near the footer. From the research I have done, IE should accept "animation-name" etc within the CSS and should be able to emulate a previous version of itself. I have tried using js to emulate an older version, too, yet this brings the same results. I'm sure I must be missing something obvious so if anyone could help, it'd be greatly appreciated, thanks.

ps. in the newer versions of IE, the images do show up, and fade out, but all at once, then do not repeat, which is obviously not the desired effect. Please refer to the Chrome version of the site to see how the animation is meant to look, thank you.

corresponding html:

```
<div id="Quote-Images" class="fadein">
    <img id="f5" src="img/quote_05.jpg" alt="">
    <img id="f4" src="img/quote_04.jpg" alt="">
    <img id="f3" src="img/quote_01.jpg" alt="">
    <img id="f2" src="img/quote_02.jpg" alt="">
    <img id="f1" src="img/quote_03.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Your question's title suggests this is an IE10 issue, but you've tagged this with IE11... Which version are you needing help on?

Comment: Use this website to help with cross-browser stuff. http://prefixr.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running it through [Prefixr](http://prefixr.com/):

I got this:

```
.fadein img {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

    -webkit-animation-name: fade;
    -moz-animation-name: fade;
    -ms-animation-name: fade;
    -o-animation-name: fade;
    animation-name: fade;

    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 32s;
    animation-duration: 32s;
}

@keyframes "fade" {
 0% {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
 }
 20% {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
 }
 33% {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
 }
 53% {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
 }

}

@-moz-keyframes fade {
 0% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }
 20% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
 }
 33% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }
 53% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }

}

@-webkit-keyframes "fade" {
 0% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }
 20% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
 }
 33% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }
 53% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }

}

@-ms-keyframes "fade" {
 0% {
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }
 20% {
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
 }
 33% {
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }
 53% {
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }

}

@-o-keyframes "fade" {
 0% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }
 20% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
 }
 33% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }
 53% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
 }

}

#f1 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -4s;
    -moz-animation-delay: -4s;
    -ms-animation-delay: -4s;
    -o-animation-delay: -4s;
    animation-delay: -4s;
}

#f2 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -8s;
    -moz-animation-delay: -8s;
    -ms-animation-delay: -8s;
    -o-animation-delay: -8s;
    animation-delay: -8s;
}

#f3 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -16s;
    -moz-animation-delay: -16s;
    -ms-animation-delay: -16s;
    -o-animation-delay: -16s;
    animation-delay: -16s;
}

#f4 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: -24s;
    -ms-animation-delay: -24s;
    -o-animation-delay: -24s;
    animation-delay: -24s;
}

#f5 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -32s;
    -moz-animation-delay: -32s;
    -ms-animation-delay: -32s;
    -o-animation-delay: -32s;
    animation-delay: -32s;
}
```

Make sure you include all browser prefixes for compatibility!

Comment: Thank you very much! The animation still doesn't seem to work on IE11 and just shows one static image but that sort of solves the problem anyway as there's no more "all-at-once" messy animation. Cheers!

Comment: Not working in IE11? Weird, it should do. It works fine for me in IE11 (transitions I mean). I'll look at code further @user3227560

Comment: I have it working now! The issue was on '@keyframes "fade"' the quotation marks were not needed, now it works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Oh glad you found it! Happy I could help! :) @user3227560

Answer (score 1):

You only have the -webkit versions for these:

```
#f1 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -4s;
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Obvious really...it took me a minute...LOL